# "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable" passing locator within expected_conditions through Python + Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, expected-condition

I'm receiving the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "[redacted]", line 69, in
>   
>       wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.ID("RptViewer_ctl09_ctl04_ctl00_ButtonLink")))
>   TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Here's the section of code I believe is causing the problem:

```
66   browser.find_element_by_id('RptViewer_ctl09_ctl04_ctl00_ButtonLink')
67   drp = browser.find_element_by_id('RptViewer_ctl09_ctl04_ctl00_ButtonLink')
68   wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
69   wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.ID('RptViewer_ctl09_ctl04_ctl00_ButtonLink')))
70   drp.click()
```

I think what's causing the issue is the "ID('RptViewer_ctl09_ctl04_ctl00_ButtonLink')" section but I'm not sure if that's true and I'm not sure of how to fix it. Any guidance is extremely appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: That line contains three function calls, so I'd start by splitting those three across separate lines, to see which one is the problem.

Comment: From the documentation `element_to_be_clickable()` takes  a single parameter of what looks like a `tuple`. Try: `wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,'RptViewer_ctl09_ctl04_ctl00_ButtonLink')))`  Note: `(By.ID,'Rpt ...`

Answer (score 1):

While using [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.wait) inconjunction with [expected_conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions) you have to enclose the locator with in a tuple as follows:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "RptViewer_ctl09_ctl04_ctl00_ButtonLink")))
```

Answer (score 0):

By.ID is a string. Not callable. Expected condition takes locator in a form of a tuple (as quamrana already suggested)